# Codeigniter View is loading view two times

Tags: php, codeigniter

This my whole index function in the controller

```
public function index(){

 if (isset($_POST['age_search'])) {

    $config['base_url'] = base_url()."school/school_reports/";
    $config['per_page'] = 20;
    $config['total_rows'] = $this->school_info_model->get_count_reports($this->session->userdata('school_name'));
    $config['num_links'] = 5;

    $config['full_tag_open'] = "<ul class='pagination'>";
    $config['full_tag_close'] = "</ul>";

    $config['first_link'] = "First";
    $config['first_tag_open'] = "<li>";
    $config['first_tag_close'] = "</li>";

    $config['next_tag_open'] = "<li>";
    $config['next_tag_close'] = "</li>";

    $config['cur_tag_open'] = "<li><a href='#'>";
    $config['cur_tag_close'] = "</a></li>";

    $config['prev_tag_open'] = "<li>";
    $config['prev_tag_close'] = "</li>";

    $config['num_tag_open'] = "<li>";
    $config['num_tag_close'] = "</li>";

    $this->pagination->initialize($config);


    if($this->uri->segment(3)){
        $page = $this->uri->segment(3);
    }else{
        $page = 0;
    }

     $age = $_POST['age'];

     $data['list'] = $this->school_info_model->get_school_all_reports_list($age, $config['per_page'], $page);
     $data['links'] = $this->pagination->create_links();
     $data['report'] = array('a','b','c','d','e','f1','g','h');



  }elseif(isset($_POST['show'])) {

            $annexure = $_POST['reports'];

             $ids=$this->school_model->get_schools_data_generic_uids();

             if ($ids) {


        $data['students'] = $this->school_model->get_school_students_data($ids);    



        foreach ($data['students'] as $h) {
                $pids[] = $h['uid'];
                    }
                $total = array_unique($pids);

                $data['total_students'] =count($total);


            if ($annexure == 'a') {


                $this->load->view('analyst/header');
                $this->load->view("analyst/age/annexure_a", $data);
                $this->load->view('analyst/footer');

            }elseif ($annexure == 'b') {


                $this->load->view('analyst/header');
                $this->load->view("analyst/age/annexure_b", $data);
                $this->load->view('analyst/footer',$data);

            }elseif ($annexure == 'c') {


                $this->load->view('analyst/header');
                $this->load->view("analyst/age/annexure_c", $data);
                $this->load->view('analyst/footer_d',$data);

            }elseif ($annexure == 'd') {


                $this->load->view('analyst/header');
                $this->load->view("analyst/age/annexure_d", $data);
                $this->load->view('analyst/footer_d',$data);

            }

 }else{

      echo "No record found";
 }

 }

      $data['classes']=$this->users_model->get_classes();
      $data['cities']=$this->general_model->get_cities();

      $this->load->view('analyst/header');
      $this->load->view("school/School_reports_generic",$data);
      $this->load->view('analyst/footer');

}
```

Here is my Code i want to know why this part of code loads view even after if condition is true in above block

```
  $data['classes']=$this->users_model->get_classes();
  $data['cities']=$this->general_model->get_cities();

  $this->load->view('analyst/header');
  $this->load->view("school/School_reports_generic",$data);
  $this->load->view('analyst/footer');
```

This view is loading right after the view which is in condition when it becomes true.

I want that when condition becomes true only view in if condition body should load.

Comment: OH i found it....I just had to put return; at the if statement body where i want to stop the execution i put it right after the condition body executes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Here is my Code i want to know why this part of code loads view even
>   after if condition is true in above block

Because in your `if / else` block after loading view,  there is no `return` or `die()` or `exit()`, so after executing code inside `if / else` block control comes till the end of function/method, and in the end you have below statements

```
$data['classes']=$this->users_model->get_classes();
$data['cities']=$this->general_model->get_cities();

$this->load->view('analyst/header');
$this->load->view("school/School_reports_generic",$data);
$this->load->view('analyst/footer');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
if (!$this->input->post()) {
    $data['classes']=$this->users_model->get_classes();
    $data['cities']=$this->general_model->get_cities();

    $this->load->view('analyst/header');
    $this->load->view("school/School_reports_generic",$data);
    $this->load->view('analyst/footer');
} esle {
    // whole first part
}
```